# Activity takes a long time to load

Tags: java, android, multithreading

My activity contains only ViewPager. I generate questions and insert them into fragments. My ViewPager contains 30 elements.I have a menu from where I launch the activity, when I first start the activity, it starts 3 seconds on average, then faster. I get ANRs in my developer console **Input dispatching timed out**. I decided to track programmatically the time between `onCreate()` and `onWindowFocusChanged()` calls.

- 2021-11-12 09:08:39.190/TAG: ONCREATE
- 2021-11-12 09:08:39.369/TAG: ONRESUME
- 2021-11-12 09:08:41.301/TAG: onWindowFocusChanged
  I believe that the problem is in creating fragments for ViewPager.I decided to create fragments for it using background threads.

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        new Handler(getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    for (int i = 0; i <= 14; i++){
                        fragmentsType1.add(QuestionFragment1.newInstance(questions.get(i)));
                    }
                }
            });

            new Handler(getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    for (int i = 15; i <= 29; i++){
                        fragmentsType2.add(QuestionFragment2.newInstance(questions.get(i)));
                    }
                }
            });

            //I insert everything into 1 list so that there are no problems with locks
            fragments.addAll(fragmentsType1);
            fragments.addAll(fragmentsType2);
    }
```

```
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return fragments.get(position);
        }
```

But I am getting error in  `FragmentPagerAdapter.getItem()` that the size of the list is 0. Because `getItem()` is called while the fragments have not been created yet. What should I do?
Here is my Fragment.

```
public class QuestionFragment1 extends Fragment implements TestActivity.DataFragmentListener {

    private OnAnswerSelectedListener callBack;
    private Question question;
    private int questionPosition;
    private int answerState;
    private int correctAnswerIndex;
    private int incorrectAnswerIndex;
    private boolean isGameOver = false;

    private ImageView[] buttons;

    private TextView title;
    private ImageView image1;
    private ImageView image2;
    private ImageView image3;
    private ImageView image4;

    public QuestionFragment1(){}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getFragmentArguments();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.questionFragment, container, false);
        initWidgets(view);
        setQuestion();
        setClickListeners();

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        boolean isNullListeners = ((TestActivity)context).checkIsNullArrayListeners();
        if (isNullListeners){
           ((TestActivity)context).initListeners();
        }
        ((TestActivity)context).registerDataFragmentListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        ((TestActivity) Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity())).unregisterDataFragmentListener(this);
        super.onDestroy();        
    }

    public static QuestionFragment1 newInstance(Question question, int questionPosition){
        QuestionFragment1 fragment = new QuestionFragment1();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putSerializable("Question", question);
        bundle.putInt("QuestionPosition", questionPosition);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);

        return fragment;
    }

    public void setCallBackListener(OnAnswerSelectedListener callBack){
        this.callBack = callBack;
    }

    private void getFragmentArguments(){
        question = (Question) (getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getSerializable("Question") : null);
        questionPosition = getArguments().getInt("QuestionPosition");
    }

    private void setQuestion(){
        title.setText(Html.fromHtml(question.getTitle()));
        image1.setImageResource(question.getAnswers().get(0).getImagePath());
        image2.setImageResource(question.getAnswers().get(1).getImagePath());
        image3.setImageResource(question.getAnswers().get(2).getImagePath());
        image4.setImageResource(question.getAnswers().get(3).getImagePath());

    }

    private void initWidgets(View view){
        title = view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        image1 = view.findViewById(R.id.image1);
        image2 = view.findViewById(R.id.image2);
        image3 = view.findViewById(R.id.image3);
        image4 = view.findViewById(R.id.image4);

        buttons = new ImageView[]{
                image1,
                image2,
                image3,
                image4};
    }

    private void setClickListeners(){
        image1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                checkAnswer(question.getAnswers().get(0), 0);
            }
        });

        image2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                checkAnswer(question.getAnswers().get(1), 1 );
            }
        });

        image3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                checkAnswer(question.getAnswers().get(2), 2);
            }
        });

        image4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                checkAnswer(question.getAnswers().get(3), 3);
            }
        });
    }

    private void btnsSetEnableOff(){
        image1.setEnabled(false);
        image2.setEnabled(false);
        image3.setEnabled(false);
        image4.setEnabled(false);
    }

    private void checkAnswerState(){
        if (answerState == 1){
            btnsSetEnableOff();
            buttons[correctAnswerIndex].setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.question_type3_correct_answer_background));
        }else if (answerState == -1){
            btnsSetEnableOff();
            buttons[incorrectAnswerIndex].setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.question_type3_incorrect_answer_background));
            buttons[correctAnswerIndex].setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.question_type3_correct_answer_background));
        }
    }

    private void checkAnswer(Question answer, int btnPos){
        if (question.isCorrectAnswer(answer)){
            answerState = 1;
            btnsSetEnableOff();
            buttons[btnPos].setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.question_type3_correct_answer_background));
            callBack.onAnswerSelected(questionPosition, answerState, btnPos, 0);
        }else {
            answerState = -1;
            btnsSetEnableOff();
            buttons[btnPos].setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.question_type3_incorrect_answer_background));
            for (int i = 0; i < question.getAnswers().size(); i++){
                if (question.isCorrectAnswer(question.getAnswers().get(i))){
                    buttons[i].setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.question_type3_correct_answer_background));
                    callBack.onAnswerSelected(questionPosition, answerState, i, btnPos);
                }
            }
        }

    }

    private void checkIsGameOver(){
        if (isGameOver){
            btnsSetEnableOff();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDataUpdate(int answersState, int correctAnswerIndex, int incorrectAnswerIndex, boolean isGameOver) {
        this.answerState = answersState;
        this.correctAnswerIndex = correctAnswerIndex;
        this.incorrectAnswerIndex = incorrectAnswerIndex;
        this.isGameOver = isGameOver;
        checkIsGameOver();
        checkAnswerState();
    }

    @Override
    public Question getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }
}
```

Comment: If your fragments are slow to create it likely means you are doing too much work in the Fragment itself. The solution is to fix the Fragment so it can load and display its own data asynchronously, not to create it like this in a handler (which is not implemented correctly anyway). You would have to post an actual Fragment that shows this issue if you wanted more specific answers...

Comment: I added my Fragment.